# How do I specialize several type on the same template function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have a generic function to read columns from my database. Its prototype in the header file is :

```
template <typename T> void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value);
```

The idea is to specialized this function to call these functions depending on the value type :

```
sqlite3_column_int64(...)
sqlite3_column_double(...)
sqlite3_column_text(...)
```

In my `cpp` file, I have written the specialization functions like this :

```
template <> void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, int& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, column);
}

template <> void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, float& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, column);
}

template <> void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, std::string& value)
{
    value = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, column));
}
```

The problem I have is that the value type when calling this function can be of the following :

```
uint32_t, int32_t, int64_t
float, double
```

I don't know how to tell that all "*integers*" types must call the function`sqlite3_column_int64`.

Same for `float` and `double` to call `sqlite3_column_double` function.

How can I do it? Is it possible at all?

---

### EDIT

The solution I use is as follow:

```
// the 3 functions in the header file
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>> sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, column);
}

template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>> sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, column);
}

template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>> sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    value = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, column));
}
```

Comment: you should look at SFINAE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to conditionally remove functions from overload resolution based on type traits using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

- [`std::is_integral<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) checks whether T is an integral type.
- [`std::is_floating_point<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) checks whether T is a floating-point type.

Your code after  using enable_if:

```
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>> sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, column);
}

template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>> sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    value = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, column);
}

void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, std::string& value)
{
    value = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, column));
}
```

Comment: I don't think your example will compile. What will the `std::string` specialization match?

Comment: @BiagioFesta Sorry it's an overload not specialization.

Comment: Yeah, now it's fine! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried your code in the ccp file, then in the header file. I got the same error in both case: `undefined reference to `void sqlite3_column_template<int>(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int&)'` and for others type as well (long long, const char*, double, unsigned int)

Comment: Your solution is working if the header file is called once. Else the function for std::string is seen defined multiple times : `multiple definition of sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)`. I used some of @Jejo code to solve this problem

Comment: @grorel The code I've written isn't a complete .cpp/.h file, so you should take care of includes and include guards.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you could combine the specializations to one single function with the help of ***[if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)***.

Where type traits:

- [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)
  has been used to check the type is an integer.
- [`std::is_floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point)
  has been used to check the type is a floating-point.
- [`std::is_same_v<T, U>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) has been used
  to check whether types(i.e. `T` and `U`) are same(used for checking
  `std::string`).

The `sqlite3_column_template` can be written now:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_integral, std::is_floating_point, std::is_same

template <typename T>
void sqlite3_column_template(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int column, T& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) 
    {
        value = sqlite3_column_int64();
        // do something more
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) 
    {
        value = sqlite3_column_double();
        // do something more
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) 
    {
        value = sqlite3_column_text();
        // do something more
    }
    else
        static_assert(false, "wrong type");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried your code in the ccp file, then in the header file. I got the same error in both case: `undefined reference to void sqlite3_column_template<int>(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int&)'` and for others type as well (long long, const char*, double, unsigned int)

Comment: Yes, no more template in the cpp file. I get the same error as in my first message :  undefined reference to `void sqlite3_column_template<long long>(sqlite3_stmt*, int, long long&)`

Comment: OK, I had a problem with my toolchain & source files... Everything compile fine now but the static_assert which lead to this error `error: static assertion failed: wrong type`. I'll use the solution posted in my post. thank you for your help